# Add BoxCollider from other object to current object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If you add a BoxCollider component to an object, it is auto sized to be a bounding box size. Is there a way to generate a BoxCollider component for another object(so it has the bounding box of that object), but then add it to the current, different object? Thanks!

Comment: In editor, copy component and paste as new. In runtime,first call AddComponent() ,second set its size to another object size.

Comment: I dont know how I didnt think of that lol